Change the size of an stl object without deform it
I'm very new to blender and also to 3d printing.
I'm trying to make a frame, and I found some  model in thingiverse but it does not have the correct measurements. So I imported it to blender but when I try to change the x scale to increase the length the ends get deformed. Is there anyway that I can just edit the length without changing how the ends look like?


(Using Blender 3.6.8)
It seems that what you would like to achieve is to "elongate" the object, not to "scale" it. In Edit Mode, you can do that by selecting faces at one end, then by extruding this selection along X axis:


...or just using G > X to move them. No need to extrude!

@JohnEason My thoughts exactly. In many cases this is even better than extruding.

Thank you very much for the help! That was exactly what I wanted :)
